# how to get icon xpm icon file of an app installed in android

Tags: android, image, icons

Hello all
am trying to list all the apps installed in the android device .
I also want to get the **icon** assocaited with these app in **xpm** format.Is there a way for this?

Thanks in advance .
kozlov

Answer (score 1):

> Hello all am trying to list all the apps installed in the android device .

Use `PackageManager` and `getInstalledApplications()`.

> I also want to get the icon assocaited with these app in xpm format.

Android does not support XPM images. XPM has been obsolete for over a decade. You are welcome to attempt your own conversion.